# How do i check if database row exist in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello how do i check if database row insert exist in laravel? i want to display something entries if > 0 and i want to display else if entries = 0. but i don t know how to do that.  i tried with forelse, if else and i got same error. Undefined variable $istProj.

```
<div class="card-body">

@if ($istoric->isEmpty())
    @forelse ($istoric as $istProj)
        <div class="mb-3">
            <table class='table'>
                <tr class="table-row-heads">
                    <th>Id Proiect</th>
                    <th>Tip actiune </th>
                    <th>Colaborator </th>
                    <th>Suma </th>
                    <th>Data </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-row-data">
                    <td>{{ $istProj->id_proiect }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $istProj->action_type }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $istProj->colaborator_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $istProj->suma }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $istProj->data }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    @empty
        <div class="card-body">
        <h1>Nu au fost gasite inregistrari</h1>
        </div>
    @endforelse
    @endif

</div>
```

```
<form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Id proiect</label>
        <input type="text" class='form-control' value="{{ $proiecte->id }}" name='id_proiect' id='id_proiect' placeholder="Id proiect">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Tip actiune</label>
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"  name='Status_Tranzactii'>
            <option selected>Alege tipul actiunii (0 = cheltuiala, 1 = plata, 2 = incasare)</option>
            <option value="cheltuiala">0</option>
            <option value="plata">1</option>
            <option value="incasare">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Colaborator</label>
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="Colab_id">
            <option selected>Alege colaboratorul (daca este cazul)</option>
            @foreach ($colaborator as $colaboratori)
            <option value="{{ $colaboratori->id }}">{{ $colaboratori->id }} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Suma</label>
        <input type="text" class='form-control' value="{{ $istProj->suma }}" name='suma' placeholder="Introduceti suma">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Data</label>
        <input type="text" class='form-control' value="{{ $istProj->data }}" name='data' placeholder="Introduceti data">
    </div>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' style="float: right;">Adauga</button>
</form>
```

How can i make that to work?

Error on line with "Suma"

Comment: How is $istoric being selected for the view? What line is this error on?

Comment: @Gavin i updated the post now. u can look again at my post.

Comment: there's something wrong with your condition. Try removing the `@if($istoric->isEmpty()) and the @endif`

Comment: same error. but the error is from the code above. i updated the post please look again at my post. Error on line with "Suma" @xenooooo

Comment: what does the error says ?

Comment: and the problem only occurs when is no rows inside my db. when i have no records in my table

Comment: @xenooooo Undefined variable $istProj

Comment: Where does the $istProj comes from ?

Comment: from my forelse loop
@forelse ($istoric as $istProj)

Comment: $istoric = IstoricProiecte::all(); IstoricProiecte = table from my db.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you already have a Collection result (From Eloquent or anywhere) and you need to do different action based on that result.

I'm,right? If yes....

To  check the amount or entries you can use `$result->count()`, so in Blade you can:

```
@if($result->count() > 0)
    Do something
@else
    Do anotherthing
@endif
```